# The custom error page is not working for URLs with the '%' sign

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

The custom error page is not working for URLs with the '%' sign.

I get the response with an error page as expected if an error occurs during request processing. However, if I try to perform the request with a '%' sign at the end (like http://localhost:8080/some-path%) I get a response like this

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1></body></html>
```

I am using Spring Boot v2.7.2 with web starter.
Error controller:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

aplication.yml:

```
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true

server:
  error:
    path: /error
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
```

According to my investigation, the error occurs in `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#postParseRequest`

```
            // URI decoding
            // %xx decoding of the URL
            try {
                req.getURLDecoder().convert(decodedURI.getByteChunk(), connector.getEncodedSolidusHandlingInternal());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                response.sendError(400, "Invalid URI: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }
```

Why does the custom response not applied? Is it possible to change the default response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the member of the Spring project:

> Unfortunately, there's nothing that we can do about this. The URI to
> which the request has been sent (http://localhost:8080/some-path%) is
> invalid as there's an incomplete %-encoded character at the end of the
> URL. This results in a failure very early in Tomcat's request
> handling, before it is able to determine to which context and servlet
> the request should be routed. As a result, when the 400 error response
> is being sent, it can't be routed into Spring Boot's custom error
> handling.

The issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35668